# Xcode 6 beta 5 won't build Swift with iOS 7.1 SDK

Tags: xcode6

Despite the release notes stating this is supported and previous version of Xcode 6 working ok, I have a rather verbose error message when trying to build with 7.1 SDK.

"iOS targets using Swift cannot be built against an SDK older than 8.0, but the effective SDK is 7.1."

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: I have seen this too... the same error appears for me - and it seems to conradict what Apple stated in July. (see http://i.imgur.com/gljIsXN.png)

Comment: Apple must be keeping builds simple for themselves/us :) We can deploy to iOS 7 but don't need the iOS SDK 7. I haven't submitted to the Apple Store with such a build. Will it work for iOS 7.1 users?

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue, but with the app store build of Xcode 6.0.1 (6A317).

The issue was that I had copied old SDK's (7.0, 7.1) into the `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs` directory. This was causing Xcode to use the wrong SDK for building.

Deleting them solved this problem for me. That'll teach me for mucking around with Xcode.

Comment: But sure there was a reason why you copied the old SDKs into your xcode. Would be nice to find a way keeping "all" versions without running into the mentioned issue.